# What does it mean to have an at sign (@) prefixing an HTML attribute token in a JQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I found [this snippet online:](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-awesome-jquery-tips-and-tricks)

```
$('a[@rel$='external']').click(function(){
  this.target = "_blank";
});
```

What does the `@` mean though? Why `@rel` and not just `rel`? I wanted to submit a code-correction to that and I don't actually know if this is a typo or not.

Comment: The `@` should not even work (for me, jQuery returns "Syntax error, unrecognized expression:"). Which jQuery version do you use?

Answer (score 5):

The `@` was deprecated in 1.2, removed in 1.3. See the [attribute selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for more details.

That's a pretty old article.

Comment: Makes sense, brings it in line with the actual [CSS attribute selector specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yep; used to be XPathy.

Answer (score 3):

`@` here means attribute. It indicates that the `<a>` element has an attribute `rel` with a value of `external`.

This is a feature of XPath. You can find more info about using XPath selectors in JQuery here:

http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#Using_CSS_and_XPath_Together